# How to handle exceptions when using MVC with Entity Framework and Repository pattern

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, repository-pattern

I have been going through a number of tutorials and sample code trying to learn unit testing and the repository pattern, and I am trying to figure out how to handle exceptions with implicitly declared types.

For example lets say I create and issue object using the following.

```
var issue = issueRepository.GetIssueById(issueId);
```

If I create this in a try catch block the variable will be scoped only to the try, so I would have to have everything related to this within the try. I could declare the issue outside of the try as a new issue, but the best practice recommendations I have been reading have said to use implicit whenever possible. Is it better to put the try catch in the repository? If so, how would you get that back to the controller?

Sorry if the question is rudimentary, but I haven't been able to find any sample code that has exception handling with these patterns.

Comment: The code in the repository is not related to the code executed against the returned `issue` is it?

Comment: Shouldn't the exception be thrown at the `Repository` level when it can't find the `Issue` by `Id`?

Comment: I don't even think  would throw an exception on a non-existent ID. Maybe if issueId was something bogus like `-1` (InvalidArgumentException) but `return null;` and checking for it seems like a better fit. (Granted, the example is most likely not the _Exact_ case but just an example)

Comment: I haven't run into any exception so far using this pattern except once when the database was down. So yes this is just an example, and I am looking for more of best practice approach.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be this, but this way is pushing the exception at the `Repository` level, this would make the caller focus on business rules more.

```
public abstract class BaseRepository<TYPE, IDTYPE>
{
  public TYPE GetById(IDTYPE id)
    {
        return getById(id);
    }

   protected abstract TYPE getById(IDTYPE id);
}

public class IssueRepository : BaseRepository <Issue, int>
{
    protected override Issue getById(int id)
    {
        var result = context.Issues.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == id);
        // or even do First() which would throw exception if not found

        if (result == null)
        {
            throw new NotFoundException("Issue was not found with Id: {0}", id);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```